# how to compress an UIImagePNGRepresentation

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using the following code to save an image captured from the camera and saves to CoreData but is very large and need to reduce it to the fullest.

```
NSData* image = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image)];
```

the length of NSData is 1048 and i need compress that as much as possible

Comment: Can you resize the image or do you need it to be the exact resolution of how the image was taken?

Comment: Does the image format need to be a PNG? We use UIImageJPEGRepresentation to save images from the camera because the second parameter is quality.

Comment: yes i can resize the image but do not know how to do that

Comment: Is it critical to store images as blob data in CD? I'd save image files to disk and only store file path in my core data.

Comment: what happens is that NSData should also be sent to a server and is very long and does not accept it, when the server is not active should be on the CoreData to be sent later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method that will resize originalImage to newSize:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)originalImage scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    @synchronized(self) 
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
        [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: btw, why do you synchronize self ?

Comment: That snippet initially was instance method. And @syncronized(self) helps to avoid race conditions.